# Spring DI using legacy objects that can't be beanified

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice

I want to translate the following Guice-based DI configuration to Spring Java-config based DI.

```
public class UserModule extends AbstractModule {

    private final User user;

    public UserModule(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
       // don't need to do any configuration
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    User provideUser() {
        return user;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton @Inject
    UserStorageService provideUserStorageService(User u) {
        return new UserStorageServiceImpl(u);
    }
}
```

The intended use is then

```
Injector userOneInjector = Guice.createInjector(new UserModule(userOne));
Injector userTwoInjector = Guice.createInjector(new UserModule(userTwo));
```

Unfortunately, Spring's AnnotationConfigApplicationContext takes in a configuration class rather than an object, so I'm not sure how to inject the a User object into its configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A separate `@Configuration` class to isolate the 'non-standard' object?

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigA {
    public @Bean User getUser () {
        // Here do whatever it takes to create/lookup the user
        return new User();
    }
}
```

Comment: But creating/looking up the CannotBeBeanified requires using objects that are scoped outside of configurations. With Guice I can pass them in as constructor args, trying to figure out how to do that with Spring.

What if the CannotBeBeanified constructor used a String or File that was only available at runtime, for example?

Comment: How do you mean scoped outside of configurations?

Comment: Sorry, I think my comment was not well written. I've updated the example in the question, hopefully its more clear? In the new example, I don't want to create new users, I want to use objects I already have a reference to, but I don't see how to do that without using a singleton.

Comment: I think I understand. Do you want to create `UserModule` objects based on existing `User` objects? Where do the `User`s come from?

Comment: Yup! Lets say the `User`s come from remote requests 

   `public interface ExposedViaRestOrSomething {
      void doSomethingFunkyWithUser(User u);
   }`